# Как достать из такого типа JSONobject его два поля в String

Tags: java, android

Не понимаю как отсюда достать две строки пробую так выдает ошибку.{"token":"122ewqelqwejqwelqewlweqwelwe","refresh":"wr2r4r2303023r23023"}

```
 JSONObject jsonToken = new JSONObject(responseOutput.toString());

 jsonToken - инициализирую из StringBuilder но там все нормально проверял

 JSONObject jsonParamRefresh = jsonToken.getJSONObject("refresh");

 JSONObject jsonParamToken = jsonToken.getJSONObject("token");

 String paramToken = jsonParamToken.toString();

 String paramRefresh = jsonParamRefresh.toString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String jsonParamRefresh = jsonToken.getString("refresh");
String jsonParamToken = jsonToken.getString("token");
```

Вы же хотите получить строки, сразу забирайте их из `JSONObject`

Comment: Да действительно, верно подмечено затупил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Это чтобы забрать строку из "token": `(String) jsonToken.get("token")`

Это чтобы забрать строку из "refresh": `(String) jsonToken.get("refresh")`